# Imported functions not working in puppeteer

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-scraping, automation, puppeteer

**Importing a long JS function from a different file:**

```
let startTheShow = require('./scraper.js');
```

And then trying to use that function on the page.

```
await page.evaluate(() => {

    startTheShow('info','hi','hi');


})
```

**What is the expected result?**
The imported function will run on the page

**What happens instead?**
"startTheShow is not defined"

Placing the raw script inside the evaluate instead of importing the module to the index, fixes the issue. Unfortunately this option makes a lot of mess in the index file. Any idea why I can't use this imported function?

Answer (score 2):

From the [docs](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageevaluatepagefunction-args):

> pageFunction `<function|string>` Function to be evaluated in the page context

`evaluate(() => startTheShow())` means there should be a `startTheShow` function in the page context which I'd assume there isn't any and the page context has no idea what `startTheShow` is. You should either pass the string version of `./scraper.js`, or the `startTheShow` function to evaluate.

Example of passing strings from docs:

```js
console.log(await page.evaluate('1 + 2')); // prints "3"
```

Comment: Oh, I understand. Do you think that there may be a way to inject this code to the page and then run it from there? perhaps page.addStyleTag from the docs: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/master/docs/api.md#pageaddstyletagoptions

Comment: @Theprocodernotreallyxd you can use [`page.exposeFunction()`](https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/v2.1.1/docs/api.md#pageexposefunctionname-puppeteerfunction) for that purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I am now using this:
await page.exposeFunction("startTheShow",startTheShow);
await page.evaluate(async function() {
   await startTheShow('erezshahaf2@gmail.com','hi','banana');
})

But it will return an Error : Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: this._pageBindings.get(...) is not a function

any idea?